# Google maps and jQuery error messages - geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to show user position on a simple google maps in my website , head section :

```
<head>
    <!--jquery ,js scripts  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--js scripts -->
    <script src="jsCode.js"></script> 
    <script src ="sirJson.js"></script>
    <!--gMap plugin API -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyAVVQuKtaYbe30ZdNueAcpcXXXIik_5Rjs"></script>
    <script src = "gmap.js"></script>    
</head>
```

And the map div :

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
```

In the js part i have tried :

```
$('#mapButton').click (function () {

        var myMap = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(myMap);
         var mapOptions = { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.552965, 43.47315),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        })  ;
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

And the user position :

```
var myMap = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(myMap);
         var mapOptions = { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        })  ;
```

Error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined and You denied permission to retrieve a position - error .

fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/rma3jzgw/ ->fix something ->show position via google maps

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: It works with jQuery ? i have tried that before , didn't combined well.

Comment: I have used this - https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map , same code .

Comment: that is what you must use. I am not getting your problem. It would be helpful if you create a code snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rma3jzgw/

Answer (score 0):

i just simply copied and pasted this scripts from 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
and it worked

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
           function initialize() {
            var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
            var map_options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.470, 96.100),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>-->
```

Comment: i have tried that : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' and still didn't solve the user position error .